# .NET Core web API accept camelCase and output snake_case

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc, api, .net-core

I have an .NET Core Web API.  Out of the box I understand that it gives you camelCase JSON when getting data back from endpoints you make. I've decided to change this default behavior to be snake case with this bit of code in my `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
    };
});
```

This works well and gives me the JSON in snake_case when I request data from an endpoint. However, now when I give it camelCase JSON for `POST` requests, it doesn't work. I like to keep my JavaScript camelCase on the front end, so it's preferable to work with camelCase when sending data. For instance, if I want to send data, I must do it this way:

```
obj: {
    some_key: "value" // works
    someKey: "value" // doesn't work
}
```

So, the question: Is there a way to output my JSON from the API endpoints as snake_case but also have it accept camelCase for `POST` bodies and other data?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4562):

> If you need to create non-default `JsonInputFormatter` or `JsonOutputFormatter` instances, use `JsonSerializerSettingsProvider` (in RC2) to initialize the `JsonSerializerSettings` instances and get the remaining constructor parameters from DI e.g. adding parameters to the controller constructor.

Sample code from the same issue:

```
options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonOutputFormatter>();
options.InputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonInputFormatter>();
options.InputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonPatchInputFormatter>();

var outputSettings = JsonSerializerSettingsProvider.CreateSerializerSettings();
options.OutputFormatters.Add(new JsonOutputFormatter(outputSettings, _charPool));

var inputSettings = JsonSerializerSettingsProvider.CreateSerializerSettings();
var jsonInputLogger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<JsonInputFormatter>();
options.InputFormatters.Add(new JsonInputFormatter(
    jsonInputLogger,
    inputSettings,
    _charPool,
    _objectPoolProvider));

var jsonInputPatchLogger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<JsonPatchInputFormatter>();
options.InputFormatters.Add(new JsonPatchInputFormatter(
    jsonInputPatchLogger,
    inputSettings,
    _charPool,
    _objectPoolProvider));
```

So I guess you basically need to adjust this code for your needs. More about the [configuring the formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting#configuring-formatters) or [adding your own formatter for input and output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-formatters#how-to-configure-mvc-to-use-a-custom-formatter) can be found on MSDN.